# How to make autoresize flex elements?

Tags: html, css

I have some squares inline:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.parent div {
  background: red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I need to resize the squares to fit in one line if the blocks are not fitted inline.

How to do that using flex?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to, for example, make the squares go on the second line if there is not enough space?

Comment: I need to auto resize the squares in small displays and show them all in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the divs to resize, you should not use absolute units such as `px`, but write them as relative size against the parent div, such as in `%`. However, you might want to max them out at a certain size before they get too big, so you might want to use a `max-width` such as follows.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.parent div {
  background: red;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 120px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```